# Error using elastic on linux server but no error on windows

Tags: r, linux, elasticsearch, ropensci

When I execute

```
elastic::Search(index=index,body=body,size=1000,scroll="3m")
```

on a linux server I receive the following error.

```
invalid char in json text. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//
```

On windows everything is fine. However, if I execute elastic::Search with a different body, it works. So here is my body.

> '{
>                      "_source":["DOC_ID", "DELIVERY_ID",
>   "CONTRIB_TS", "LANG", "SYS_NOT", "SURVEIL"],
>                      "query": {
>                      "bool": {
>                      "must": [
>                      {"match_phrase": { "CONTENT" : "XXX" }}
>                      ],
>                      "filter": [{ "term"  : { "DELIVERY_ID" : "100" } },{ "term"  : { "SYS_NOT" : "0" } }]
>                      }
>                      },
>                      "highlight": {
>                      "pre_tags" : [""],
>                      "post_tags" : [""],
>                      "fields" : {
>                      "CONTENT": {"fragment_size" : 200}
>                    }
>                    }
>                    }'

Comment: I think its a problem with multiple cores. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: (`elastic` maintainer here) seems like you're getting back HTML somehow given what you show for the error. the JSON parser then can't parse HTML as you'd imagine. I'd try running `connect` like `connect(errors = "complete")` so hopefully you can get a more useful Elaticsearch stack trace - no idea about why it works on windows and not linux

Comment: Okay, I just executed `connect(errors = "complete")` before I execute my query. Then i get `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//
                     (right here) ------^
Called from: parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char)`

Comment: get verbose curl output and see if that helps, e.g., https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/blob/master/man-roxygen/search_egs.r#L140  that should help you determine if the right request is being sent